# Selector/Ripple/Tint for ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, ripple

I have an ImageView with a Bitmap as as its source. I want to give a selector/ripple/tint to the ImageView. When I click on ImageView I want to show a white color **(#AAFFFFFF)** tint with alpha.

This is what I have tried.

**selector_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue_a" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/green_a" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/red_a" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Then I set this as the ImageView's background using `android:background="@drawable/selector_image"`. However this changes the background which is behind my Bitmap, hence is not visible on top of the Bitmap.

Have a look at this video for help
[Image Ripple Effect](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B0NGgBg38lWWdjdXZUtDc2szc2c/animation-responsiveinteraction-surfacereaction-030202_TouchRipple_PressRelease_xhdpi_002.webm).

The Video have a ripple effect. I want this ripple in post-lollipop devices and a simple tint without ripple for pre-lollipop.

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

For ripple effect affect you don't need a selector but a ripple like

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                      android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
            </shape>
        </item>
 </ripple>
```

and put this under **drawable-v21** folder.For pre lollipop device create a a normal selector and set it as background.Also both the files should have the same name.

Comment: For pre-lollipop I did used selector as I have mentioned in my question. However the selector was changing the background. Since the background is behind the Bitmap of ImageView I can't see it. I want the selector to be in the front (on top of Bitmap of ImageView).

Answer (score 0):

How about ImageButton instead of ImageView. You can easily set a background selector for different states.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get the nice ripple effect on API 21+, and fallback to a light shadow on older platforms, make sure you are using [appcompat-v7 support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), then you can use `?selectableItemBackground` to get the effect.

Now the question is about how to add the effect on top of your `ImageView`. Here are some possible solutions.

1. If you are using `ImageView`s as items in a `ListView`, you can set the following attributes for `ListView`.

   ```
   <ListView
       ...
       android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
       android:listSelector="?selectableItemBackground" />
   ```
2. If you are using the `ImageView` inside a `FrameLayout`, you can set the ripple as foreground of the `FrameLayout`.

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       ...
       android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground" />
   ```
3. You can always add a wrapping `FrameLayout` over the `ImageView` to get the foreground ripple. Note that `andriod:foreground` is only added to all the views since API v23, so we cannot utilize that.
4. You can also extend `ImageView` to add backward-compatible foreground support to it. If you want to go this way, leave a comment and I'll write more about it here.

---

**Edit:**

Checkout my implmentation of a `RelativeLayout` with foreground: https://gist.github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/9067a68d6e836389933c

Drop the `attrs.xml` into `res/values`, and `ForegroundRelativeLayout.java` into your own package, then replace all occurences of `RelativeLayout` to `ImageView`.

Then you can reference the custom view in your XML. Instead of using `ImageView`, use the fully qualified name of your custom view (`com.example.android.ForegroundImageView` for example) as the tag name, and add `android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"` to it. This way it should work properly now.

(It should work properly if you don't target API 23 which will enable foreground for all views on API 23 (otherwise it won't be enabled), resulting in two foregrounds - His code is written far before the release of API 23. If you target API 23, you can workaround this by adding some API level check yourself.)

I was also planning to release a library for `android:foreground` backward-compatibility. If I had the time :)

---

One more thing, solution #3 of wrapping the `ImageView` with a `FrameLayout` should always work (easily), without all the work required above. You need to leverage it with the slight performance loss yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Your first 3 points are of no use to me in this case because I am neither using ListView nor FrameLayout. However, I can give a try to your 4th point. Please help me implement it.

Comment: Thanks. This really worked. I have a question though. I agree both 4th and 3rd are suitable in my case. However, which one is better in terms of performance and memory? In 3rd, there is one more layout hierarchy and in 4th there is a custom view.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with explaining 2nd point as well. I wanna give it a try. That also seems a good approach. I will appreciate that.

Comment: In my own concept, I believe custom view is not much an overhead compared to nested view hierarchy, anyway they are also java classes just as the framework ones, while nested views are ususally frown upon in official performance guides. So I believe only custom views that are incorrectly written can be the cause of performance problem. And in practice I've wrote a lot of custom views to tweak some minor behavior of framework views, it worked great. In conclusion, I believe #3 is better, especially when there are some mature library implemention. (I'm planning)

Comment: Solution #2 seems quite clear to me, adding an `android:foreground` attribute to the parent `FrameLayout` will make the parent `FrameLayout` draw the ripple over its child `ImageView`. If you have any question on this, feel free to ask it again.

Comment: Can i use something else instead of "foreground" property in attrs.xml? I am planning to change my API level to 23. But I still want to show this foreground tint.

Comment: @NiteshKhatri Of course you can - though it might look ugly. The best solution if you are going with #4 is to check for target SDK - I'll post my solution on a `RelativeLayout` now, and you can replace all `RelativeLayout` to `ImageView` for use.

Comment: @NiteshKhatri Updated in my answer.